# Was Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories ever ported to anything outside of PS2?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories

I can't find a clear answer to whether, or not Chain of Memories was ever ported to anything outside of the Play Station 2. I thought that KH 1.5 had it, but it was actually Re:Chain of Memories (the second one of the set), and 2.5 doesn't seem to have it easier.

So was Chain of Memories ever ported to anything outside of PS2?

Comment: Chain of Memories = Re: Chain of Memories.  It is the same game.

Comment: Why did they add the Re: part to it then? Remake? I guess. It made it seem like it was some sort of sequel.

Comment: Nope.  They updated it for Japan, with cutscenes.  There are some other minor differences, but it's the same game, crappy battle system and all.

Comment: I don't know. It seemed to do pretty well according to [metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/game/game-boy-advance/kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories).

Comment: obviously the opinion of @Frank, not that of the general audience. But yeah, it is the same game.

Comment: @Timelord64 I understand that, but I was just pointing it out. Anyway I knew from the get go that this would be marginally different as it was originally designed for handheld use, but I'm willing to wing it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories was initially released for [Game Boy Advance](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts:_Chain_of_Memories).

When it was ported to [PlayStation 2](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_Re:Chain_of_Memories) it was titled "Kingdom Hearts RE: Chain of Memories" and contained gameplay tweaks and changed the game to 3D.

The updated game was re-released in Kingdom Hearts 1.5 HD Remix, under the same title, on PlayStation 3. KH 1.5 is a compilation title and is an HD update for this game, the original KH, and scenes from another game for the higher resolution PS3.

See [this section of the Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories page on the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts:_Chain_of_Memories#Versions_and_merchandise) for more on releases and merchandise.

Comment: To clarify, I am assuming you mean 'release' when you say port. Re is a remake, designed for a more powerful console, with significant graphical upgrades. If you actually mean "port", where the game is released as close to the original as possible, then no. There have been no ports.

Comment: Updated a bit of the info. Re: CoM is released in 1.5 for the PS3, and was released for PS2 packaged with KH: FM in Japan, and as it's own title internationally. However, as noted, there has been no "direct" port, and the gameplay mechanics were tweaked in the port to accommodate different controllers and more capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The Original Chain Of Memories is the GBA version RE:Chain of Memories is the PS2 port Which was updated for Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5